# How does an upcasted Banishment function on creatures with different distastes?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, spell-components, targeting

The [*banishment*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/banishment) spell requires "an item distasteful to the target" as a material component.

The spell can be upcasted to affect multiple creatures.

**What happens when the different creatures you target are very different from one another, and thus have different distastes?**

Example: a booger used as a distasteful item to a Priest of Cleanliness, but the spell is upcasted to also affect a Barf Monster, which does not care about boogers.

Comment: A+ imagery in the last section

Comment: This question is assuming the lack of a focus, which although I disagree in this spell's case, foregoes this requirement?

Comment: What terrible circumstance could possibly have caused a Priest of Cleanliness to ally with a Barf Monster? This is a mystery that must be solved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## An Arcane/Holy Focus avoids this problem

It should go without saying that it's moot if the caster is using an Arcane Focus; *Banishment* specifies neither that the object have a cost, nor that the object is consumed. So it's a perfectly legal spell to be cast with an Arcane/Holy Focus, and thus the spell works perfectly fine when upcast with a focus.

Otherwise...

## The Caster needs to hold both/all of the objects

It's a tricky ruling, but the description for Banishment's material component says *"an item distasteful to the target"*, and upcasting the spell essentially means increasing the number of targets of the spell. So I think it would be necessary for the caster to hold the material components for both (or all) of the targets, not merely one of them.

Comment: Some spells (Such as delayed blast fireball) have multiple components by default. I think 'rooting around in your pouch' is the action, regardless of what you are getting.

Comment: "As far as I know, retrieving two components from a component pouch (or otherwise pulling two components from your backpack/inventory) would probably exceed the limit established by the Free Item Interaction portion of the Caster's turn, and would thus require the caster to waste a turn gathering components." - Retrieving the material components of a spell (or accessing a component pouch/spellcasting focus) is [part of the casting of the spell](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/861638734889926656), and doesn't use your object interaction - assuming you already have the components.

Answer (score 9):

### Just fine, RAW, due to how component pouches and spellcasting foci work

First, don't take the specific material components for each spell too seriously; they are hold-overs from the early days of D&D, and are mostly there for flavor. (They are also, more often than not, jokes. Message is a copper wire...a phone line, get it? And *don't get me started* on the legumes for Gust of Wind.)

Mechanically, in 5th edition, they have been trumped by two classes of objects: the **Component Pouch**, and **Spellcasting Focus** (whether Arcane, Druidic, or Holy Symbol).

---

The **Component Pouch** basically lets you ignore those material components, as per the PHB Equipment. (Bolding added by me.)

> A component pouch is a small, watertight leather belt pouch that has compartments to hold **all** the material components and other special items you need to cast your spells, except for those components that have a specific cost (as indicated in a spell's description).

The **Spellcasting Focus** mechanically works the same way as per the PHB Spellcasting.

> A character can use a component pouch or a spellcasting focus (found in chapter 5, “Equipment”) in place of the components specified for a spell.

Jeremy Crawford, the only person on the Wizards payroll who is allowed to make official public rule clarifications, has [backed that up via Twitter](https://twitter.com/armando_doval/status/861635833354481664?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw%7Ctwcamp%5Etweetembed%7Ctwterm%5E861636231947362310&ref_url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.sageadvice.eu%2F2017%2F06%2F16%2Fis-the-intent-behind-a-component-pouch-that-you-reach-into%2F).

> If you're using a spellcasting focus or a component pouch, free components are abstracted away.

So, since the component for Banishment doesn't list a gold piece value, it's covered.

---

RAW, you only need to worry about having those material components if you are without a Component Pouch or Spellcasting Focus. Since every 'full' casting class is given a focus or component pouch at character creation, the intent is they're abstracted away by default. So, the only time you'd *really* have to worry about it in RAW is if you have been stripped of all your equipment.

I can think of one edge case; a Good-aligned spellcaster with a Focus wanting to Banish a Good-aligned extra-planar creature. Then, depending on the flavor of the campaign, I could see a DM ruling that you'd need to obtain something distasteful to make it work, since the holy symbol or crystal or whatever probably isn't.